# Can't properly set up GLFW with C++ and VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++17, glfw

I'm on a Windows, using c++17 and trying to use GLFW in one of my projects. This is what I tried, yet it doesn't work:

I opened up an empty folder in VS Code, and added `src` and `Dependencies` folders. Then downloaded the GLFW pre-compiled binaries. I created a folder inside `Dependencies` for GLFW, then pasted the `include` and `lib-vc2022` folders from the pre-compiled binaries inside it.

Then I opened `c_cpp_properties.json` from inside the `.vscode` folder in the workspace and added `${workspaceFolder}/Dependencies/GLFW/include/**` in the `"includePath"` list.

I ran c++ code which started with `#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>`. I got this error:

```
App.cpp:2:10: fatal error: GLFW\glfw3.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I followed a tutorial I found all throughout this, and tried others. Still cannot get it to work. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove ** from path: "${workspaceFolder}/Dependencies/GLFW/include"

Comment: Gives out the same error.

Comment: You may give me a link to project? The problem must be in your path.